# Executing code before and after downloading a file with Datatables (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables to create some tables with data. I am using the option they have to include a download CSV button. However, since I am working with large amounts of data, I wanted to put a "Loading, please wait..." gif on the screen so users know it is downloading. However, the gif loading I have requires that I activate it before the downloading starts, and deactivate it after the downloading finishes (really it's just adding a class to the body which makes it a bit transparent and adds a wheel gif). I haven't found a way to run code before and after download. I think I can do before with `action`, but not after.

Can anyone help me out with this? Is there a way to do code before download and after download? Or, in absence of that, is there maybe a better way I can implement a waiting gif while it prepares the csv for download?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. DataTables does not provide any download processing events, and you have no chance to intercept a download in javascript, if you are not controlling it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the csv-button and call the original action inside it. This enables you to show a custom loading-indicator while the export is being processed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let table = $('#example').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'csv',
      text: 'CSV Export',
      action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
        console.log('csv button clicked');
        this.processing(true); // show indicator on button
        console.log('before csv export');
        config.filename = 'my-export'; // set filename
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, button, config); // call export-action
        console.log('after csv export');
        this.processing(false); // hide indicator on button
      }
    }],
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test-1</td>
      <td>Test 1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test-3</td>
      <td>I dont know!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test-2</td>
      <td>Another...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha-1</td>
      <td>Apple Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha-2</td>
      <td>Banana Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha-3</td>
      <td>Coconut</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Beta-1</td>
      <td>Beta</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Beta-2</td>
      <td>Not Alpha</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha-1</td>
      <td>Apple Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha-2</td>
      <td>Banana Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alpha-3</td>
      <td>Coconut</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Beta-1</td>
      <td>Beta</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Beta-2</td>
      <td>Not Alpha</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```